# Input string was not in a correct format - Slot Mchine App

Tags: c#, list, int32

I get the error: 'Input string was not in a correct format'..... I am running an if else calculation and then populating a label with the result the variable is declared as decimal then ToString('C') to the label...

```
List<string> moneyWon = new List<string>();

     private void calculateAmountWon()
     {
         moneyWon.Add(amountWonlabel.Text);

         decimal won = moneyWon.Sum(str => Convert.ToInt32(str));             

         moneyWonLabel.Text = won.ToString("C");
      }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Seems pretty apparent that `moneyWon` contains a string that isn't convertible to an int.

Comment: My guess is that the strings are formatted as currecny (`$0.00`) which isn't paresable to `int`.

Comment: Did you try debugging to see what won contains? Did you try bigger integers in case it overflows int32

Comment: I am really new to C# and programming in general. I was creating  txt. file before I changed it a list, so I know it is being stored as "C" or $1.00....

Comment: Let me try some of these suggestions....Thanks!

Comment: Bingo! Took out the "C" in the ToString and it now works.....Thank you guys!! Thank you for your patience!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you're outputting I'm assuming that your strings are formatted as currency with a currency symbol and two decimal places.  If that's the case you can change your parsing to:

```
decimal won = moneyWon.Sum(str => decimal.Parse(str, NumberStyles.Currency));
```

You're still vulnerable to invalid formats but if the values are all set programatically then they should be predictable.

Another option is to use a list of numeric types and parse up front:

```
List<decimal> moneyWon = new List<decimal>();

private void calculateAmountWon()
{
     moneyWon.Add(decimal.Parse(amountWonlabel.Text, NumberStyles.Currency));

     decimal won = moneyWon.Sum();             

     moneyWonLabel.Text = won.ToString("C");
}
```

Comment: Having some trouble with the NumberStyles.Currency... I am working in Visual Studio Express 2012.... don't know if that matters or if it is a using problem...

Comment: @ghowell Add `using System.Globalization` to the top of your class file.

Comment: D Stanley - Yes, That fixed it! I like your solution because it lets me keep the Currency format on the label I am pulling from. Thanks for the lesson!!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that will throw that error is the `Convert.ToInt32(str)` call. One of the items in the `moneyWon` list is not a valid `int` value.

You should probably also declare `moneyWon` as a `List<int>` and store all the values as `int`'s instead of `string`'s. It doesn't make sense to store everything as a string and then convert it to `int` when you need it.